# Dynamics AX 2012 MenuItemButton behavior

Tags: axapta, x++, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I have a button that has a Action in its MenuItemType. Is it possible to make it run two classes sequentially? I have one class that runs an external program and another to sync it. I want to combine the two operations in one button.

Answer (score 1):

You could write another class which invokes the two desired classes sequentially and use this new class for the button.